# 3D in android application

Tags: java, android

i am working on an android application that is supposed to show a human body in 3D. Is there any API that i can use?

Plus I want to the captured face image to be the face of that 3D avatar.

Comment: From your request you don't look to be "working" much... I mean: why not directly search for an API implementing the whole app you are are supposed to do? Maybe one with even the tile and credits already set... Sorry for the sarcasm, but your request doesn't look to be about programming, but more about "finding everything already done"...

Comment: yes i want that already done, because making the 3D figure is not the main thing i am supposed to do. processes are to be performed on the figure, that is the real thing, which i do not want already done.

Comment: I see, but you can't expect to find it ready anyway: Кристиян Кацаров answer is correct: doing the kind of application you seem to be wanting to do "usually costs lot of work and money".

Comment: yeah i might be looking for a short-cut. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My official answer is that you first learn how you make this with unity, then learn some openGl and then post your concrete question. This is too general and the answer in code usually costs lot of work and money.